# node js ssh keygen giving , Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported OpenSSH private key type: ssh-ed25519 even after pem option

Tags: node.js, ssh, ssh-keygen

My company uses ed25519 and nodejs version 10. I see the error,
"[image]

I deleted the keys from the .ssh( this i was fine since I am starting to build new) and regenerated adding the -m pem option as [image] I copied the .pub contents to my app  for validation.

I still see this error.. Is there anything I am missing? or is it picking up the old keys from somewhere?

Any pointers would greatly help me..

thanks

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, When exactly are you getting the error? Executing some command like `npm install`??

Comment: i am seeing it when doing noder sever.js.. npm install is fine

Comment: What exact node.js version and what exact `ssh2` module version are you using?

Comment: Ssh is openssh 8.8 amd node is 10.24 that my team uses

Comment: I was referring to the `ssh2` node.js module that you appear to be using, either directly or indirectly (`npm ls` from your project root should probably show it somewhere).

Comment: got it... I see , +-- ssh2@1.11.0 , -- ssh2@0.4.15  -- ssh2-streams@0.0.23 when i do npm ls

Comment: My guess is the error is coming from whatever dependency is using the older version of `ssh2`. `ssh2` v1.x definitely has ed25519 support. Seems like the dependency chain needs to be updated so that a modern version of `ssh2` is used.

Comment: Thank you mscdex.. I see this $ npm ls |findstr ssh2
| `-- ssh2@0.4.15
|   `-- ssh2-streams@0.0.23
+-- ssh2@1.11.0  .. does it mean it has two version of ssh2 now? 0.4.15 and 1.11?